# placing error messages in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to place error messages in gridview how can i do this

```
 public class EmployeeMetadata
    {
      [Required]
      [StringLength(20,ErrorMessage="First Name must be less than 20 characters.")]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Last Name must be less than 20 characters.")]
      public string LastName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Country must be less than 10 characters.")]
      public string Country { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to populate a GridView then you need to get away from string concatenations and start thinking in an OOP way.

GridView can be populated with any construct that implements `IEnumerable`, so you can do this:

VB:

```
Dim ListOfErrors as New List(Of MyError)
```

C#:

```
List<MyError> ListOfErrors = new List<MyError>();
```

Where `MyError` is (minimally) defined as:

---

VB:

```
Class MyError
    Public Property RowNumber as Int32 = 0
    Public Property Error as String = String.Empty
End Class
```

C# :

```
class MyError
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }
    public String Error { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then as you find errors, rather than build a concatenated string, you instead fill the List:

VB:

```
Dim AnError as New MyError
AnError.RowNumber = i
AnError.Error = "Some error"

ListOfErrors.Add( AnError )
```

C#:

```
MyError AnError = new MyError();
AnError.RowNumber = i;
AnError.Error = "Some error";

ListOfErrors.Add( AnError );
```

---

And when you're done finding errors, Bind the list to the GridView

VB:

```
// this will autogenerate columns for all public properties in MyError
Gridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

// attach List
Gridview1.DataSource = ListOfErrors

// Bind
Gridview1.DataBind()
```

C#:

```
Gridview1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
Gridview1.DataSource = ListOfErrors;
Gridview1.DataBind();
```

Comment: i need to do it using c#

Comment: hope this clarifies how to convert VB to C#

Comment: You never mention, in your original post or it's tags, Excel.  But if all the error messages are being stored in a table in a database, do you have read access to that table of error messages?